# Why are checkboxes always checked, regardless of default or configuration?

Tags: forms

Weird situation in a form:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\title{Test of checkbox}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\begin{Form}
\CheckBox[name=Test]{This} \\
\CheckBox[name=Test,checked=false]{Or This}
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

If you believe the manual, checked=false is the default behaviour.

I am seeing both boxes above as being checked. Platform: MacTeX 2014 on Mac OSX Mavericks 10.9.2.

Comment: Compiling with MiKTeX 2.9 and viewing with Adobe Reader 11 on Win7, both are unchecked.

Comment: `TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)`, Ubuntu 14.04, GNOME Document Viewer 3.10.3 = unchecked.

Comment: That is puzzling. This MWE shows both boxes checked on MacTeX 2014.

Comment: I can verify that the checkboxes are both checked when viewed with Preview while they are both unchecked when viewed with Adobe Reader 11 on Mac.

Comment: Thanks for checking on this. Does this mean that Preview has a bug?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem with MacTeX 2014.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a bug/'feature' of Preview, not a TeX issue.